# Latent class analysis error

Tags: r

Before I start I must say I don’t have much experience with R. So any help will be appreciated.
I am trying LCA and installed package `poLCA`. The program was running fine, however, after I installed Rstudio V0.99 program code started throwing an error message (pasted below).
Suprisingly the same code comes up with results in my co-workers system with same version of Rstudio. I tried to reinstall the earlier version of Rstudio but the problem remained. Tried to debug the function but not sure if I am doing it correctly.

The code:

```
seg.df <- read.csv("http://goo.gl/qw303p")
View(seg.df)
seg.df.cut <- seg.df
seg.df.cut$age <- factor(ifelse(seg.df$age < median(seg.df$age), 1, 2))
seg.df.cut$income <- factor(ifelse(seg.df$income < median(seg.df$income), 1, 2))
seg.df.cut$kids <- factor(ifelse(seg.df$kids < median(seg.df$kids), 1, 2))
summary(seg.df.cut)
seg.f <- with(seg.df.cut, cbind(age, gender, income, kids, ownHome, subscribe)~1)
library(poLCA)
set.seed(02807)
seg.LCA3 <- poLCA(seg.f, data=seg.df.cut, nclass=3)
```

I get the below error message:

```
Browse[2]> c
    Error: could not find function "poLCA.vectorize"
    In addition: Warning message:
    In matrix(b, ncol = (R)) :
     data length [2] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of columns     [3]
```

Please suggest how to fix this.

Comment: Rstudio should not be influencing your code. Do you mean different version of R? What  versions do you use? Do you have identical package versions?

Comment: Try reinstalling `poLCA`.  Might be an issue with a package in a path different from the one RStudio is using.

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for your comment. I not only reinstalled the package but re-installed Rstudio too. but doesnt work. I have never seen or heard of an issue like this ever.

Comment: Hi Roman, I too believe Rstudio is not influencing the code. But could not figure out what's going wrong. By R version i meant R 3.2.2.

Comment: I know this is not helping much but running your code above works perfectly here on my computer. It must be an installation issue (with the package - I hardly doubt it is related to RStudio). Have you tried running the code directly in R (ie., outside RStudio) to see if you get the same error message?

Comment: Hi Ekstroem, Yes it works in R. But nothing improved in R studio. Tried all possible solution suggested. But none works.